# no setup button in unity for google play service setup

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

When I was trying to setup Google Play Game service for my Unity project, the pop-up window looks a bit weird. I cannot find the "setup" button.Here is the screenshot:

[image]

This is different from what I saw on the tutorials. It ask me to go to Google Player Developer console to do the setup however I could not find where to do this. Can anyone help me with this setup process?

Comment: Play games console is an online dashboard, the 'Setup' button is there :))
plugins get updated frequently, got to adapt

Comment: But I cannot find it... is it under game service tab or the application tab?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same view when going into my Google Play Games popup. You should be able to scroll down on this popup with your mouse wheel, despite the fact that there is no scrollbar. After scrolling to the bottom, there should be a "setup" button that you can click on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11737812)

Comment: @VadimMartynov How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should abuse the review queues to delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664)

Comment: @Undo this answer is totally useless. In the question there is an screen-shot without any scrollbars. Also, it's not fully relevant because GPD console not depend to the source window. 
How can this answer helps anyone? And why we should not delete useless answers?

Comment: @VadimMartynov I expanded upon the answer a bit. I would argue that the original answer did in fact answer the question, but definitely did not provide enough backup information. And though I agree the screenshot does not have a scrollbar for the full popup, in this case, that simply means the creator of this feature did not consider that different resolutions may not be able to see the full content. This popup can be scrolled with the mouse wheel or other such methods.